# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'. My code does not work and when I compare it to the answers it is the same?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, attributeerror

I am doing the Python Crash Course book by Eric Matthes and I am doing exercise 6-9 called favourite places. When I try this code I get this error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'

```
favourite_places = {
'mum': ['hong kong', 'orkney'],
'dad': ['slovenia', 'the alps', 'scotland highlands'],
'james': 'hong kong',
}

for name, place in favourite_places.items():
print(name.title() + "'s favourite places are " + place.title())
```

But I compared it to the code for the answers for this exercise and I can't tell what i have done wrong. Here is the code from the answers,

```
favorite_places = {
'eric': ['bear mountain', 'death valley', 'tierra del fuego'],
'erin': ['hawaii', 'iceland'],
'ever': ['mt. verstovia', 'the playground', 'south carolina']
}

for name, places in favorite_places.items():
print("\n" + name.title() + " likes the following places:")
for place in places:
    print("- " + place.title())
```

In the answers he has put place.title() and it gets no errors but when I do it, it does. Thanks if you can help

Comment: In your code you have 'place' being set to a list. Try printing out "place" in your last line and you'll see it's returning a list. `title()` function only works on strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here in that you are missing this:

```
for place in places:
    print("- " + place.title())
```

`places` is a `list` and `place` in `list` is a `str`. The `title()` attribute only applies to `str`. So when you do:

```
for name, place in favourite_places.items():
print(name.title() + "'s favourite places are " + place.title())
```

You need to iterate over `place` to get the `str` within it to call `title()` on.

Like this:

```
for name, place in favourite_places.items():
    print(name.title() + "'s favourite places are ")
    for p in place:
       print(p.title())
```

You need to also make `james` `value` a 1 element list for this to work:

```
favourite_places = {
'mum': ['hong kong', 'orkney'],
'dad': ['slovenia', 'the alps', 'scotland highlands'],
'james': ['hong kong'],
}
```

Lastly, make sure you are being careful of indentation. I assume you have it properly indented in your code and you just copied it to stack wrong but your `print` statement needs to be indented so it occurs in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
favourite_places = {
'mum': ['hong kong', 'orkney'],
'dad': ['slovenia', 'the alps', 'scotland highlands'],
'james': 'hong kong',
}

for name, place in favourite_places.items():
    print(name.title() + "'s favourite places are \n-{}\n".format( "\n-".join([i.title() for i in place]) if isinstance(place, list) else place.title() + "\n"))
```

The problem is the "mum" and "dad" are list and list don't have titles so you need to iter over each item of them and call the title method.

Comment: You are disregarding the fact the the last dictionary value is a string, while the others are lists.

Comment: look at my answer there is the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Two main issues:

1. In your code, the dictionary value is of type `list` in teo items, and a `str` in the third. This makes it impossible to treat them the same way.
2. In your code, you do not iterate over all the items in the dictionary values.

Fix the `"hong kong"` value to be a list (with a single element), and include the two nested loops in your code.

Comment: list don't have title method so changing "hong kong" to list won't help him.

Comment: Except, OP is comparing code to some reference design, in which all values *are* lists.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron I simply added a condition to my answer if place is not a list.